# Runtime connectionstring of entityframework and add/update/delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I am able to set connectionstring of entityframework at runtime through the following code; but i don't know how to do add/update/delete of database records. Entity that needs to be added/updated/deleted is Products(id,name).

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder ecsb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
ecsb.Metadata = @"res://*/Model2.csdl|res://*/Model2.ssdl|res://*/Model2.msl";
ecsb.Provider = @"System.Data.VistaDB";
ecsb.ProviderConnectionString = @"data source=test.vdb4;password=password";
using (var context = new DbContext(ecsb.ConnectionString))
{
    // how to add new record/update/delete
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Also what tutorials / books have you studied?

Comment: I solved it using entityconnection instead of DbContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that your Product class is called `Product` you use the following code:

```
var product = context.Set<Product>().Find(id);
context.Set<Product>().Remove(product);
```